# Is it possible to enter USB-C Gadget Mode using only dhcpcd?

Tags: usb, ssh, connection, dhcp, gadget

I've been following tutorials like this one to make USB 'Gadget Mode' work on the Pi:
https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2019/11/02/pi4-usb-c-gadget/

However the other day I had an issue getting it to work with my android phone and it was pointed out to me that I shouldn't be mixing dhcpcd with edits to /etc/network/interfaces

That being the case, is it possible to get the USB Gadget Mode working with just using dhcpcd.conf?

Comment: you are mixing apples and rocks ... DHCP is a protocol for contacting a server and obtaining an IP address on a network ... USB is a serial data bus